# Unable to save users: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<>` out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (BufferedInputStream)

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I am so tired of my problem. 
I have a JSON, I am trying:
 1. To transform it into POJO using Jackson, and  custom method in Spring Boot app
 2. Save with  H2 Db with Hibernate:
 With JSON below it isn't working.
Without  **"Countries":** everything working fine.
 Please explain to me, what means "Countries" and how to save it to the Db?
Also what means last  "Date": "2020-04-05T06:37:00Z" after ], and should I save it to DB too?

JSON:

```
 {
      "Countries": [
        {
          "Country": "ALA Aland Islands",
          "CountryCode": "AX",
          "Slug": "ala-aland-islands",
          "NewConfirmed": 0,
          "TotalConfirmed": 0,
          "NewDeaths": 0,
          "TotalDeaths": 0,
          "NewRecovered": 0,
          "TotalRecovered": 0,
          "Date": "2020-04-05T06:37:00Z"
        },
        {
          "Country": "Afghanistan",
          "CountryCode": "AF",
          "Slug": "afghanistan",
          "NewConfirmed": 18,
          "TotalConfirmed": 299,
          "NewDeaths": 1,
          "TotalDeaths": 7,
          "NewRecovered": 0,
          "TotalRecovered": 10,
          "Date": "2020-04-05T06:37:00Z"
        }
      ],
"Date": "2020-04-05T06:37:00Z"
    }
```

My POJO:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Country {

    @JsonProperty("Countries")
    ArrayList <Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();  

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;  

    @JsonProperty("Country")
    private String country;  

    @JsonProperty("CountryCode")
    private String countryside;  

    @JsonProperty("Slug")
    private String slug;  

    @JsonProperty("NewConfirmed")
    private Integer newConfirmed;  

    @JsonProperty("TotalConfirmed")
    private Integer totalConfirmed;  

    @JsonProperty("NewDeaths")
    private Integer newDeaths;  

    @JsonProperty("TotalDeaths")
    private Integer totalDeaths;  

    @JsonProperty("NewRecovered")
    private Integer newRecovered;  

    @JsonProperty("TotalRecovered")
    private Integer totalRecovered;  

    @JsonProperty("Date")
    private String date;

    public Country() {
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
2020-05-10 01:07:52.255  INFO 27321 --- [  restartedMain] com.vicchern.Covid19JsonToDb             : Started Covid19JsonToDb in 3.786 seconds (JVM running for 4.595)
**Unable to save users: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.vicchern.domain.Country>` out of START_OBJECT token**
 at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 2, column: 1]
2020-05-10 01:07:52.632  INFO 27321 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-10 01:07:52.633  INFO 27321 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-10 01:07:52.642  INFO 27321 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
```

I want to transform it into POJO with Jackson, with this custom method in Spring Boot app and save with database:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Covid19JsonToDb.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(UserService userService){
        return args -> {
            // read JSON and load json
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            TypeReference<List<Country>> typeReference = new TypeReference<>(){};
            InputStream inputStream = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("/json/countries.json");
            try {
                List<Country> users = mapper.readValue(inputStream,typeReference);
                userService.save(users);
                System.out.println("Users Saved!");
            } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Unable to save users: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }
```

This is my service:

```
@Service
public class CountryService {

    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    public CountryService(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
        this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<Country> list() {
        return countryRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Country save(Country country) {
        return countryRepository.save(country);
    }

    public void save(List<Country> countries) {
        countryRepository.saveAll(countries);
    }
}
```

Repository implements JpaRepository (no custom input)

I already read a lot of stuff here and on the internet. I have seen answers about "wrappers" for Lists. But how to deal with it, please help me with advice.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems with the code you have posted above.

**1)** You are expecting a list of `Country` but, your JSON is actually an Object of `Country`.

```
TypeReference<List<Country>> typeReference = new TypeReference<>(){};
```

It should be changed to,

```
TypeReference<Country> typeReference = new TypeReference<>(){};
```

**2)** You just have one class representing countries and it's information but, actually you need two different classes as `Countries` is not part of the country information object (You are expecting it to be a part of it by including it in the same class).

The split classes should look something like this,

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Country {
    @JsonProperty("Countries")
    List<CountryMetadata> countries = new ArrayList<>();

    public Country() {
       // ...
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class CountryMetadata {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;  

    @JsonProperty("Country")
    private String country;  

    @JsonProperty("CountryCode")
    private String countryside;  

    @JsonProperty("Slug")
    private String slug;  

    @JsonProperty("NewConfirmed")
    private Integer newConfirmed;  

    @JsonProperty("TotalConfirmed")
    private Integer totalConfirmed;  

    @JsonProperty("NewDeaths")
    private Integer newDeaths;  

    @JsonProperty("TotalDeaths")
    private Integer totalDeaths;  

    @JsonProperty("NewRecovered")
    private Integer newRecovered;  

    @JsonProperty("TotalRecovered")
    private Integer totalRecovered;  

    @JsonProperty("Date")
    private String date;

    public CountryMetadata() {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I will mark Country as "@Entity", Hibernate will need an "@Id" field and it will be another table? Also, Hibernate will say:  **nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: country, for columns: [org.hibernate.mappingnested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: country, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(countries)].Column(countries)]**